# How to find the number of pairs of non-coprimes in two given arrays in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to go about finding the number of non-coprimes in a given array?
Suppose

```
a = [2, 5, 6, 7]
b = [4, 9, 10, 12]
```

Then the number of non-coprimes will be 3, since You can remove:

```
(2, 4)
(5, 10)
(6, 9)
```

```
n = int(input())
a = list(map(int, input().split()))
b = list(map(int, input().split()))
count = 0
len_a = len(a)
len_b = len(b)
for i in range(len_a):
    for j in range(len_b):
        x = a[i]
        y = b[j]
        if(math.gcd(x,y) != 1):
            count += 1
print(count)
```

This is in reference to :https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/computer-game/problem

I am receiving 8 as output.

Comment: That's because you are counting all of `(2, 4), (2, 10), (2, 12), (5, 10), (6, 4), (6, 9), (6, 10), (6, 12)` (that's 8) all which are non-coprime pairs.

Comment: it has to be 3. It is [2,4], [5.10], [6,12]. All others dont have a difference of 1. So they are not co-primes.

Comment: The problem is not so easy as you think. Try to understand it in a better way. I will suggest having a look on https://cp-algorithms.com/graph/dinic.html

Comment: @JoeFerndz, having a difference of one and being co-prime are two very different things...

Comment: @ShlomiF, thanks for clarifying. Based on this... https://byjus.com/maths/co-prime-numbers/#:~:text=A%20Co%2Dprime%20number%20is,order%20to%20form%20co%2Dprimes. it looks like the co-primes are `(2,9), (4,5), (5,9), (5, 12), (4, 7), (7, 9), (7,10), (7,12)`. Thats 8 are co-primes. The ones that are not co-primes are the ones schwobaseggi mentioned.

Comment: @JoeFerndz, right, but it turns out the OP was asking the wrong question ;-)
See my answer bellow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you expect the answer to be 3?
You're pairing 5 and 10, so you're obviously looking at pairs of elements from `a` and `b` disregarding their position.

Just print out the pairs and you'll see why you're getting 8...

```
import math
from itertools import product

a=[2, 5, 6, 7]
b=[4, 9, 10, 12] 
print(sum([math.gcd(x, y) != 1 for x, y in product(a, b)]))  # 8
print([(x, y) for x, y in product(a, b) if math.gcd(x, y) != 1])  # the pairs
```

---

Update: After reading the problem the OP is trying to handle, it's worth pointing out that the expect output (3) is the answer to a *different* question!
**Not** how many pairs of elements are not coprime, but rather how many non-coprime pairs can be removed *without returning them into the arrays*.
This question is actually an order of magnitude more difficult, and is not a matter of fixing one's code, but rather about giving the actual problem a lot of mathematical and algorithmic thought.

See some discussion [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/66858/there-are-n-numbers-find-the-maximal-set-of-pairwise-non-coprime-numbers)

---

Last edit, a sort-of solution, albeit an extremely inefficient one. The only point is to suggest some code that can help the OP understand the point of the original question, by seeing *some* form of solution, however low-quality or bad-runtime it is.

```
import math
from itertools import product, permutations

n = 4

def get_pairs_list_not_coprime_count(pairs_list):
    x, y = zip(*pairs_list)
    return min(i for i in range(n) if math.gcd(x[i], y[i]) == 1)  # number of pairs before hitting a coprime pair


a = [2, 5, 6, 7]
b = [4, 9, 10, 12]

a_perms = permutations(a)  # so that the pairing product with b includes all pairing options
b_perms = permutations(b)  # so that the pairing product with a includes all pairing options

pairing_options = product(a_perms, b_perms)  # pairs-off different orderings of a and b
actual_pairs = [zip(*p) for p in pairing_options]  # turn a pair of a&b orderings into number-pairs (for each of the orderings possible as realized by the product)

print(max(get_pairs_list_not_coprime_count(pairs_list) for pairs_list in actual_pairs))  # The most pairings managed over all possible options: 3 for this example
```

Comment: Hey, think you can help me fix the code? I am new at this and would really appreciate a fix with details.

Comment: See my edited answer. Hope that helps point in the right direction :-)

Comment: @AnandaSaiA - If this helped please upvote/accept, if not please explain what's missing

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer should be 8 itself. Out of the 4*4 possible combinations of numbers that you are comparing, there are 8 coprimes and 8 non-coprimes.

Here is an implementation of the code with the gcd function without using math and broadcasting to avoid multiple loops.

```
import numpy

a = '2 5 6 7'
b = '4 9 10 12'

a = np.array(list(map(int,a.split())))
b = np.array(list(map(int,b.split())))

def gcd(p,q):
    while q != 0:
        p, q = q, p%q
    return p

def is_coprime(x, y):
    return gcd(x, y) == 1

is_coprime_v = np.vectorize(is_coprime)
compare = is_coprime_v(a[:, None], b[None, :])

noncoprime_pairs = [(a[i],b[j]) for i,j in np.argwhere(~compare)]
coprime_pairs = [(a[i],b[j]) for i,j in np.argwhere(compare)]

print('non-coprime',noncoprime_pairs)
print('coprime',coprime_pairs)
```

```
non-coprime [(2, 4), (2, 10), (2, 12), (5, 10), (6, 4), (6, 9), (6, 10), (6, 12)]
coprime [(2, 9), (5, 4), (5, 9), (5, 12), (7, 4), (7, 9), (7, 10), (7, 12)]
```

Same solution but using the math.gcd() -

```
import math
import numpy

a = '2 5 6 7'
b = '4 9 10 12'

a = np.array(list(map(int,a.split())))
b = np.array(list(map(int,b.split())))

def f(x,y):
    return math.gcd(x, y) == 1

fv = np.vectorize(f)
compare = fv(a[:, None], b[None, :])

noncoprime_pairs = [(a[i],b[j]) for i,j in np.argwhere(~compare)]
print(noncoprime_pairs)
```

```
[(2, 4), (2, 10), (2, 12), (5, 10), (6, 4), (6, 9), (6, 10), (6, 12)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the answer to be 3 in your example, I would assume you are counting the number of values in `a` that have at least one non-coprime in `b`.

If that is the case you could do it like this:

```
from math import gcd

def nonCoprimes(A,B):
    return sum(any(gcd(a,b)>1 for b in B) for a in A)

print(nonCoprimes([2,5,6,7],[4,9,10,12])) # 3
```

So, for each value in `a` check if there are any values of `b` that don't have a gcd of 1 with the value in `a`